# Get metadata from torrent file using BDecode

Tags: php

I' am trying to get the name and size of the torrent. I' am using BDecode: [Parse and extract metadata from BitTorrent files](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3473-PHP-Parse-and-extract-metadata-from-BitTorrent-files.html) Class to get the information from the torrent file.

**Var_dump Results**

```
array(1) {
  ["info"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["files"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["length"]=>
        int(735053240)
        ["path"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(54) "BULLET RAJA [2013] -HDRiP XViD MP3  [D3Si MaNiACs].avi"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["length"]=>
        int(3226657)
        ["path"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(10) "sample.mkv"
        }
      }
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(50) "BULLET RAJA [2013] -HDRiP XViD MP3  [D3Si MaNiACs]"
    ["piece length"]=>
    int(1048576)
    ["pieces"]=>
    string(14100) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

**What I have done so far**

```
<?php
    require_once 'class.bdecode.php';

    $torrent = new BDECODE('myfile.torrent');
    $results = $torrent->result;

    print '<pre>';
    var_dump($torrent->result);
    print '</pre>';

    echo '<hr/>';

    foreach($results as $value){
        echo $value['name'];
    }

    foreach($results as $length){
        foreach($length as $value){
            echo $value["length"];
        }
    }

?>
```

My problem, I was able to get the name of the torrent but was not able to get the file size of the torrent. I' am getting this error.

```
BULLET RAJA [2013] -HDRiP XViD MP3 [D3Si MaNiACs]
Notice: Undefined index: length in D:xxxxxxxx\example.php on line 27

    Warning: Illegal string offset 'length' in D:xxxxxx\example.php on line 27
    B
    Warning: Illegal string offset 'length' in D:xxxxxx\example.php on line 27
    �
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name of torrent:

```
$torrent->result['info']['name'];
```

file list with length:

```
if(isset($torrent->result['info']['files'])) { // for directory torrent
    foreach($torrent->result['info']['files'] as $file) {
        echo implode('\\',$file['path']).' - '.$file['length'];
    }
} else {  // for single file torrent
    echo $torrent->result['info']['name'].' - '.$torrent->result['info']['length'];
}
```